# How filter FIND -E . REGEX using beginning and end of the file name?

Tags: shell-script

I'm currently using this command to get a list of files :

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)'
```

Using that command, I would get this list :

**Now :**

```
documentA.pdf
documentB.jpeg
001documentC.png
...
```

My aim is to filter this list, so I would only get files beginning with 3 integers and ending with the extensions previously set.

**Goal :**

```
001documentC.png
```

How can I tweak the command `find -E . -regex` so I would get such behaviour ? I have created a regex string : `([0-9][0-9][0-9]).*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)`, tested on [regexPal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/) but I couldn't make it work with the find command.

Comment: are you still putting the speechmarks around it? `'([0-9][0-9][0-9]).*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)' ? I can't see anything obviously wrong with this ...

Comment: Looks like an uncommon behaviour of `find`. What's your `find` version?

Comment: What does the `-E` option mean? It doesn't work with my `find`.

Comment: According to `man find` the whole path is checked, so `find . -regextype awk -regex '.*/[0-9][0-9][0-9].*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)'` works for me.

Comment: That did not work on my terminal. I'm using MacOs an zsh, that may be the reason why. Another example which should have worked did not, that's why I think zsh may be responsible.

Comment: From a quick look at osx's find man page, it seems you should take care to include the slash and use \d instead of [0-9]. With `find -E . -regex '.*/\d\d\d.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)'` do you get an error message or just no files found?

Comment: No files were returned.

Answer (score 1):

Found the perfect solution thanks to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843828/os-x-find-in-bash-with-regex-digits-d-not-producing-expected-results)

```
find -E . -iregex '.*/*\.(jpg|png|eps|gif)'
```

Test :

```
$ touch documentA.pdf documentB.jpeg 001documentC.png 0documentD.eps 0000documentE.pdf
$ find -E . -iregex '.*/[0-9]{3}.*\.(jpg|png|eps|gif)'

./001documentC.png
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the filter I posted earlier in my comment: `'.*/[0-9][0-9][0-9].*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)'` where I pointed out the whole path is filtered (and therefore you should add a slash before the filename). You commented it didn't work probably because you copy/pasted the whole line instead of just the filter. Option `-regextype awk` is the (GNU `find`) equivalent of  `-E` (in MacOS `find`).